# skin_styles.css and PNG images are not found in smart gwt

Tags: smartgwt

I specify the theme as:

my smartgwt-skins has css and images under com\smartclient\theme\enterpriseblue\public\sc\skins\EnterpriseBlue

But when I execute the code in brower, it complaints that skin_styles.css and PNG images are not found. What goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by turn on the GWT debug level to "ALL" in Eclipse, then I saw the path name's capitalization is wrong. Then I renamed the module with lower cases. It works now.